# R, How to set row names attribute as numeric from character?

Tags: r

I'm new to R and would like to know how I can set attribute of row name as numeric.
I was trying to sort data frame by row names with

```
df[ order(row.names(df)),]
```

and the result was like

```
       A    B    C    D    E
1     13    6    4    4    3
10    16    5    3    8    3
100    6    4   12   14    5
101    2   14   15    3   10
102    5    2    2    9    5
103    9    1   12    3   15
104   15    1    1    8    2
105    2   10   14    7    4
106    6    2   10    2    9
107    3    1    1    3   22
108   11    4    1    6   15
109    4   29    2    6    2
11     6   29    1    4    1
```

I have tried

```
row.names(df) <- attr(df, "row.names")
row.names(df) <- as.numeric(row.names(df))
```

But when I check row name again, it comes back to

```
[1] "character"           "vector"              "data.frameRowLabels" "SuperClassMethod"
```

I don't know what to do.. Please help me

Comment: Try `df[ order(as.integer(row.names(df))), ]` or `df[ order(attr(df, "row.names")), ]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From R's help on `?row.names`:

> All data frames have a row names attribute, a character vector of length the number of rows with no duplicates nor missing values.

This means that the row names will always be a character vector. You would need to use workarounds as suggested in the comments to make them "usable" as integers, basically always coercing. One suggestion could be that you create an `id` column of class integer and do not use `row.names` as id:

```
df$id <- as.integer(row.names(df)) 
df[order(df$id), ]
```

Omitting `row.names` also seems to be the way to go with popular data frame rethinking such as data.table or tibble - none of those use row names.