# Change row.names from num to chr

Tags: r, dataframe, row, names

I have a data.frame in R and the row.names are a character and I would like them to be numeric. I've tried to find the same issue like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54264980/r-how-to-set-row-names-attribute-as-numeric-from-character) but it doesn't work.

Here is my code:

```
attr(DF1, "row.names") 
[1] "1"  "2"  "3"  "4"  "5"  "6"  "7"  "8"  "9"  "10" "11" "12" "13" "14" "15" "16" "17" "18" "19" "20"
```

after I do what I linked above:

```
DF1$id <- as.integer(row.names(DF1)) 
DF1[order(DF1$id), ]
```

I get the same result:

```
attr(DF1, "row.names") 
[1] "1"  "2"  "3"  "4"  "5"  "6"  "7"  "8"  "9"  "10" "11" "12" "13" "14" "15" "16" "17" "18" "19" "20"
```

and I would like the result to be as in with dataframe D2:

```
attr(DF2, "row.names") 
[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the help page `?rownames` it says (emphasis mine)

> For a data frame, value for **rownames should be a character vector** of non-duplicated and non-missing names (this is enforced), and for colnames a character vector of (preferably) unique syntactically-valid names. In both cases, value will be coerced by as.character, and setting colnames will convert the row names to character.

You could make them an integer like this.

```
df <- data.frame(x = 1:3)
rownames(df) <- as.character(5:7)
attr(df, "row.names") 
#> [1] "5" "6" "7"

rownames(df) <- as.integer(rownames(df))
attr(df, "row.names")
#> [1] 5 6 7
```

Note that `row.names` will always return a character vector. See `?row.names`.

```
row.names(df)
#> [1] "5" "6" "7"
```